# How do I send a request to an API that isn't public facing?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mariadb, fetch

Currently, I am setting up a test scenario in which I host a public facing web server on one machine and a REST API & MariaDB server on a separate machine that isn't public facing. Ideally, I want a user to be able to open a page served by Machine A (hosted on port 80/443) which is capable of firing off HTTP requests to an Express app running on Machine B (no public facing ports).

When I'm on my local network, I can achieve this by using Machine B's local IP address (let's say `10.0.1.32`), but if I am outside of my network, the `fetch` fails every time. I assume this is because the client machine is what is trying to fire off the HTTP request, but I have no idea what I should do next.

Here's an example from the project I spun up. I modified it a bit so things like the URL are hardcoded in.

```js
fetch(`http://10.0.1.32/login`, {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'cors',
            cache: 'no-cache',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({un: 'someusername', pw: 'somepassword'})
        }).then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => alert(data));
```

If it helps at all, I am building the front end with React. I'm not sure if there are any React-specific solutions, but I figured I'd throw that out there just in case.

Comment: You should have to make the server on public facing(Server/machine where api is written). Database server will be on private and it will be connect through private IP

Comment: I think your api is fail in current scenario because api is under private subnet/instance

Comment: You would typically host the API server on the same private network as your web server and not allow any public access to the API server (private, local IP address only).  Then, the web server can be reached by the public, the API server cannot be reached by the public and the web server can reach the API server.